# Fastest method to network two machines for direct file sharing?

Tags: network

I have two Macs and need to provide the fastest possible connection between them at the most affordable cost for file sharing of video editing resources.  These are older Mac Pros (2010) and so I cannot simply use Thunderbolt between them.  I was thinking about 2 10GbE NICs and simply setting them up under a different isolated subnet between them.  It seems that FW800 would still be slower than 10GbE.

I was hoping to find a PCIe Thunderbolt adapter, but clearly that's not available from what I'm seeing.  I suppose I could run 2 [USB 3.1 cards](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0196YO9JI), but I don't know if there's a trick to do USB<->USB networking on macOS with that.

Are there any other options that are superior or more cost effective to accomplish this?

Comment: More detail is needed about the methods you'll use for file sharing. **What version of macOS is in use?** Will you be using Apple Server software on one Mac Pro or just the built-in file sharing in macOS? How many additional disks are in use other than the boot drives? Will you be attempting to edit video files on one Mac Pro over the network from the second Mac Pro? What editing software are you using?

Comment: 10.12.x; Apple Server will be utilized; 4 internet drives are being shared (RAID); if possible; FCPX mainly, but general file transfer is done a lot as well to and from for various other tasks that are related to software development and 3D rendering.

Comment: @ylluminate "Internet drives"? Please add the RAID type (0|1|0+1|5|6)  hard|soft SSD|HDD...

Comment: It's a RAID5 array.